# why multiple of four pattern in pascal triangle will not generate?

Tags: javascript

I tried to get the pattern in Pascal triangle from multiple of four. My code is work up to 56 rows only, then after pattern will not generate. I think after 56 rows, entire numbers of Pascal triangle are very large. Can anyone help me to solve this error? My html code mentioned follow:

```js
function printPascalTriangle() {
            document.getElementById("pascal").innerHTML = "";
            var rows = document.getElementById("numRows").value;
   var nr1 =  document.getElementById("nRow1").value;
            var de1 = document.getElementById("dNum1").value;
         
            var arr = generatePascal(++rows);
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                
                div.className = "divblock"
                for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = arr[i][j];
                    
                    span.className = "block";
                    div.appendChild(span);
     if((i)==nr1){
                   if((arr[i][j])%de1==0){
                      div.appendChild(span).style.backgroundColor='green';
       

                   } 
                }
               
                }
                document.getElementById("pascal").appendChild(div);
            }
        }
         function printrow(){
            document.getElementById("pascal_l").innerHTML = "";
            var rowss = document.getElementById("numRows").value;
            var de = document.getElementById("dNum").value;
            var arr = generatePascal(++rowss);
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var div2 = document.createElement('div');
                
                div2.className = "divblock"
                for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    var span2 = document.createElement('span');
                    span2.innerHTML = arr[i][j];
                    
                    span2.className = "block1";
                    div2.appendChild(span2);
                
                   if((arr[i][j])%de==0){
                      div2.appendChild(span2).style.backgroundColor='green';
       

                   
                }
                }
                document.getElementById("pascal_l").appendChild(div2);
            }
        }

        function generatePascal(n) {
            var arr = [];
            var tmp;
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = [];
                for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    if (j == i) {
                        arr[i].push(1);
                    } else {
                        tmp = (!!arr[i - 1][j - 1] ? arr[i - 1][j - 1] : 0) + (!!arr[i - 1][j] ? arr[i - 1][j] : 0);
                        arr[i].push(tmp);
                    }
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

```css
.container {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .block {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: .8em;
            width: 2em;
        }
  
   .block1 {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: .8em;
            width: 1em;
        }

        .divblock {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

        }

        #pascal {
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of rows for pascal Triangle" style="width:70%" id="numRows"> <br><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder=" Enter row number" style="width:30%" id="nRow1"> Divisible by 
  <input type="text" placeholder=" Number" style="width:30%" id="dNum1">
        <input type="button" " value="Go " name="Go " onClick="printPascalTriangle()"> <br><br>
  <div id="pascal"></div>
   .........View pattern.........<br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="divisible by " style="width:66.5%" id="dNum">
        <input type="button" value="Go " name="Go " onClick=" printrow()">
        <div id="pascal_l"></div>
    </div>
```

this code i coded to generate two-pascal triangle, one pascal triangle is generate color for given row only.other triangle generate pettern with divisibility 4.

Comment: I can generate up to 180 row using your code in chrome, although the row is a bit ugly. What browser are you using?

Comment: I also use google chrome..

Comment: Can you add a code snippet(click ctrl+M when editing post) that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: sorry, i could't understand, what i want to do?

Comment: Take a look on [how to create code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)